# web.xml localhost servlet mapping

Tags: servlets, web.xml, servlet-mapping

I am having a UI5 project in eclipse and trying to do servlet mapping in web.xml and want to update localhost to point to a odata url for db entries, right now UI loads fine but it gives error for data coming from odata url . this is what I am trying to do

```
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SearchPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>http://my.abc.com/xyz/odata/abc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. The url pattern is supposed to be a path inside your webapp. You need to learn what servlets are and how they work.

Comment: I am a ui5 developer and work on JS and odata. Absolutely no knowledge of servlets - so just trying to figure out on how to make things work here. thanks